# Set navigation bar title from sending controller in ios8

Tags: ios

this line worked fine in ios7 and returns the correct string from the sending view controller to set the nav bar title in the receiving VC:

self.navBar.title = ((CalendarViewController *) self.presentingViewController).dateLabel.text;

however in ios8 it returns a null string

anyone any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I sorted this one out myself.

The solution is that under iOS 8, in the modal segue from the sending vc to the receiving vc there is a new segue attribute called 'Presentation' which defaults to 'Default' (no, seriously) - anyway, I changed this to 'Current context' and my variable is now successfully passed to my receiving vc.

I think I read somewhere that this will cause the app to crash under iOS 7 but as all my devices have been upgraded to iOS 8 I was not able to verify this.

I hope this helps somebody else.